# Shapefile to raster using Rioxarray

Tags: python, shapefile, rasterio, rioxarray

I want to convert a shapefile to a raster.
Normally when using rasterio, I would be able to open the raster, copy the metadata, and then write the shapefile to a raster. That would look like this:

```
rst = rasterio.open(rst_fn)
meta = rst.meta.copy()
meta.update(compress='lzw')

with rasterio.open(out_fn, 'w+', **meta) as out:
    out_arr = out.read(1)

    # this is where we create a generator of geom, value pairs to use in rasterizing
    shapes = ((geom,value) for geom, value in zip(counties.geometry, counties.LSAD_NUM))

    burned = features.rasterize(shapes=shapes, fill=0, out=out_arr, transform=out.transform)
    out.write_band(1, burned)
```

This time, I have opened a raster using the rioxarray Python package. When I then try to copy the metadata in order to write a shapefile to a raster, I get an error. Any thoughts on this?

```
raster = rioxarray.open_rasterio('raster.tif')
meta_2 = raster.meta.copy()
```

Here I obtain the error: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'meta'

Anyone knows how to tackle this? I prefer using the rioxarray package since it is really easy to use for raster data.

Comment: Have you seen geocube: https://github.com/corteva/geocube ?

Comment: Thanks! Using it now.